# Scanning multiple lines using single scanner object

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

I a newbie to java so please don't rate down if this sounds absolute dumb to you

ok how do I enter this using a single scanner object

> 5
>
> hello how do you do
>
> welcome to my world
>
> 6 7

for those of you who suggest

```
scannerobj.nextInt->nextLine->nextLine->nextInt->nextInt,,,
```

check it out, it does not work!!!

thanks

Comment: it works with `scannerobj.nextInt->nextLine->nextLine->nextInt->nextLine->nextInt->nextLine..` check it out!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: please give a generic answer meaning which can be used on any set of multiple lines!!!

Comment: Instead of this create separate method to print value and write scanner code there.
then call the method in loop and your data

Comment: @Creative_Cimmons `please give a generic answer meaning which can be used on any set of multiple lines!!!` You might want to add that as a requirement within your question.

Comment: @DanTemple definitely. I'm surprised -_-

Comment: @RafaEl  yup it works if and only if you add an extra nextLine for enter part

Comment: @Creative_Cimmons yes, exactly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner  in    = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Please specify how many lines you want to enter: ");        
    String[] input = new String[in.nextInt()];
    in.nextLine(); //consuming the <enter> from input above

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = in.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.printf("\nYour input:\n");
    for (String s : input) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Sample execution:

```
Please specify how many lines you want to enter: 3
Line1
Line2
Line3

Your input:
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Comment: Thanks, a plus one for this line `in.nextLine(); //consuming the <enter> from input above`

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Sol{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

       while(sc.hasNextLine()){

           System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the scanner uses space as a delimiter. In order to scan by lines using forEachRemaining, change the scanner delimiter to line as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
    scanner.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Scanner  in    = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ");        
String[] input = new String[in.nextInt()];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i] = in.nextLine();
}

for (String s : input) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: That will not work properly, because `in.nextInt()` consumes the int value, but not the line break. So your first for-loop iteration will instantly write that line brake into your input[0].

Answer (score 0):

You can try only with lambda too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.forEachRemaining(input -> System.out.println(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        int first = console.nextInt();
        String second = console.nextLine();
        String third = console.nextLine();
        int fourth = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);
        System.out.println(third);
        System.out.println(fourth);
}
```

so you get them in line by line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

may be we can use this approach:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
       str0[i] = sc1.nextLine();
       System.out.println(str0[i]);
   }
```

that is we create the scanner object every time before we read the nextLine. :)